# Data compression at distribution level in SQL Server replication

Tags: sql-server, compression, replication

I have SQL Server transactional replication setup.

For one of the server I am facing slowness due to limited network bandwidth. Is there any way to **compress** data at **distribution** level only.

Comment: You can’t compress, but you can change where the agents run, which sometimes makes a difference if you have network latency.

Comment: If you have some $ to throw at it you can look into WAN accelerators, which will use compression and manage TCP acks differently to overcome the effect of latency on TCP throughput.  A quick search shows there are some open source WAN optimizers, but I have no idea how mature, reliable, and supportable they are.